# Facebook pay dialog in iframe?

Tags: facebook

In my canvas application I perform redirect to Facebook pay dialog and it appears inside app iframe with Facebook header and footer (so they are doubled). The option "display=iframe" is not allowed for this type of dialog so I can't see any way to avoid doubled headers and footers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trigger the dialog from the javascript SDK instead?

Comment: @lgy, It's more comfortable for me to process user actions at server side. Also, FB api documetation gives that direct link to pay dialog and it seemes to be ok to use it somehow.

Comment: It is, but you can't iframe it by linking directly to it, is display=popup an option for you?